# Aggregations in Elasticsearch cutting string instead of taking everything

Tags: elasticsearch

Having the following simple mapping:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/transaciones/ -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "ventas": {
            "properties": {
                "tipo": { "type": "string" },
                "cantidad": { "type": "double" }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Adding data:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/transaciones/ventas/1 -d '{
    "tipo": "Ingreso bancario",
    "cantidad": 80
}'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/transaciones/ventas/2 -d '{
    "tipo": "Ingreso bancario",
    "cantidad": 10
}'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/transaciones/ventas/3 -d '{
    "tipo": "PayPal",
    "cantidad": 30
}'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/transaciones/ventas/4 -d '{
    "tipo": "Tarjeta de credito",
    "cantidad": 130
}'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/transaciones/ventas/5 -d '{
    "tipo": "Tarjeta de credito",
    "cantidad": 130
}'
```

When I try to get the `aggs` with:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/transaciones/ventas/_search?pretty=true -d '{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "tipos_de_venta": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "tipo"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

The response is:

```
  "took" : 15,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "tipos_de_venta" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "bancario",
        "doc_count" : 2
      }, {
        "key" : "credito",
        "doc_count" : 2
      }, {
        "key" : "de",
        "doc_count" : 2
      }, {
        "key" : "ingreso",
        "doc_count" : 2
      }, {
        "key" : "tarjeta",
        "doc_count" : 2
      }, {
        "key" : "paypal",
        "doc_count" : 1
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see it cuts the strings `Tarjeta de credito` into `Tarjeta`, `de`, `credit`.
How can I take the entire string without using on the mapping `not_analyzed` on `tipo`? My desired output would be `Ingreso bancario`, `PayPal` and `Tarjeta de crédito`, on the response would be something like this:

```
 "aggregations" : {
    "tipos_de_venta" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "Ingreso bancario",
        "doc_count" : 2
      }, {
        "key" : "PayPal",
        "doc_count" : 1
      }, {
        "key" : "Tarjeta de credito",
        "doc_count" : 2
      } ]
    }
  }
```

PS: I'm using ES 2.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `tipo` field is an analyzed string. The right way to do this is to create a `not_analyzed` field in order to achieve what you want:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/transaciones/_mapping/ventas -d '{
    "properties": {
        "tipo": { 
           "type": "string",
           "fields": {
               "raw": {
                   "type": "string",
                   "index": "not_analyzed"
               }
           }
        }
    }
}'
```

Then you need to reindex your documents and finally you'll be able to run this and get the desired results:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/transaciones/ventas/_search?pretty=true -d '{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "tipos_de_venta": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "tipo.raw"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

**UPDATE**

If you really don't want to create a `not_analyzed` field, then you have another way using a `script` `terms` aggregation but it can really **kill the performance** of your cluster

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/transaciones/ventas/_search?pretty=true -d '{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "tipos_de_venta": {
            "terms": {
                "script": _source.tipo"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: I know I can do this using `not_analyzed` (as I state on the post). I want to know if there's any other possibility to achieve my goal without using it.

Comment: A little question. The reason of not using the `not_analyzed` on the `tipo` field is because someone maybe wants to search on the term itself. Using that `tipo.raw` whould make that I can make searches directly on `tipo` and get the aggs on `tipo.raw` (like two different things)?

Comment: Yes that's correct, you can still search on `tipo` and run your aggregation on `tipo.raw`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just a little question, how can I easily `reindex my data` ?

Comment: Thanks! Final question, can I reindex using the same index name in old and new? This means, on the ES docs example, using `twitter` as old and `twitter` as new index (instead of` `new_twitter`): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-reindex.html

Comment: Yes, you can do it

Comment: @Vel after testing, you can't `reindex` using the same name. You get the error `Validation Failed: 1: reindex cannot write into an index its reading from `